# Am I correct in my assumption about an error on this assignment operator?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, assignment-operator

Richard Gillam in his ["The Anatomy of the Assignment Operator"](http://icu-project.org/docs/papers/cpp_report/the_anatomy_of_the_assignment_operator.html) probably makes a wrong statement when he says the following, just at the start of his paper:

"One correct answer to this question would look something like this:"

```
TFoo&TFoo::operator=(const TFoo& that)
{
    if (this != &that)
    {
        TBar* bar1 = 0;
        TBar* bar2 = 0;

        try
        {
            bar1 = new TBar(*that.fBar1);
            bar2 = new TBar(*that.fBar2);
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            delete bar1;
            delete bar2;
            throw;
        }

        TSuperFoo::operator=(that);
        delete fBar1;
        fBar1 = bar1;
        delete fBar2;
        fBar2 = bar2;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

I think the author is wrong, for if `TSuperFoo::operator=()` throws, `bar1` and `bar2` will leak.

Comment: Wow `try-catch`, that has to be the _worst_ way of writing _exception safe_ code...

Comment: Later in the article the author offers a solution using auto_ptr's which I think is correct.

Comment: `auto_ptr`s? Those that have been deprecated?

Comment: I presume unique_ptr was not available at the time

Comment: Copy-swap comes to mind. @user1042389, `boost::shared_ptr` probably was, though.

Comment: @user1042389: _Copy-swap_ is generally the best way of implementing an _exception-safe_ assignment operator... That said, I agree with you that the author is wrong.

Comment: One more thing comes to my mind when I look at this code... after some time I developed a habit, that in situations where I'm forced to work with naked pointers I always assign `NULL` to them after `delete` call (even when I'm sure that no one will access that pointer, I "null" it still)...

Comment: @K-ballo I'll be glad to accept your answer. I was just curious to know if I was missing something, which doesn't seem to be the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There would be no memory leak if it looks like this:

```
Tbar* pBar = NULL;

try
{
    pBar = new Tbar();
}
catch (...)
{
    delete pBar;    // clean memory if it was allocated
    throw;          // error was not handled properly, throw it to caller
}

delete pBar;        // no exception was caught, clean the memory
```

But in case that before the last `delete`, there's another code that might throw an exception, than you're right and there's indeed a possible path that leads to memory leak, since in such a case the allocated memory would never be cleaned up.

It's just sad that people write a code that don't use great features this language provides to avoid such an ugly memory management. Usually either objects with automatic storage duration are sufficient and you'll find yourself following [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom, or in situations where dynamic allocation is necessary, then it's good idea to wrap those naked pointers with some objects still... smart pointers help a lot.

Comment: The OP pointed out that `TSuperFoo::operator=` may throw, outside the `try-catch`

Comment: @K-ballo Sorry, I haven't noticed it. Thanks for pointing it out, I've edited the answer, it should be fine now :)